# Does Azure create a copy of an Azure Function on the back end?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, servicebus

I am trying to troubleshoot a problem where I run an Azure Function locally on my instance and have it disabled on the Portal. After sending some data through I can see that it successfully hits my local Azure Function but never hits it again after. Strangely enough the data appears to still go through my channels of Queue - Function - Queue - Function but never hits the breakpoints on my local machine after the first successful run. Triple checking the Portal I can see that it is definitely disabled which leads me to believe there might be another instance of the Azure Function running about. I've confirmed that no other devs are working on it so I've also ruled that out...

Looking at https://[MY_FUNCTION_NAME].scm.azurewebsites.net/azurejobs/#/functions I see that there seem to be duplicates of some of my functions with varying statistics on the repeats. My guess is that Azure might be tracking my local instances when I start them but I see the "Successful" green numbers go up on both versions of the function when I pass data through. Blocked out the function names but replaced the matching ones with matching colors (blacked out bars are just single functions I was too lazy to color code). The red circles indicate the function of interest that have different success statistics.

[image]

Has anyone else run into this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there were duplicate functions in a Slot setting... Someone put them there to get deployment options set up but they left the project and never noted it.

Hope this saves someone some frustrations at some point!